# How to convert month number to full month name in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a month column in my table. The month numbers are stored in this month column like 1 for january, 2 for feb and so on.

How do I convert the numbers into month names such as january, february, march etc.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(7, 'MM'), 'MONTH') AS monthname FROM DUAL;
```

[outputs](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/1277)

```
monthname
---------
JULY
```

If you really want the month names in lower case or capitalised, you can also use:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(7, 'MM'), 'month')
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(7, 'MM'), 'Month')
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey, that's a nice little aspect of Oracle's date conversion I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to specify for your language, you can use like this;

`SELECT to_char(TO_DATE(6, 'MM'),'MONTH','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Turkish') from dual;`

it returns a Turkish month name  : Haziran

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a value after the formatted month like Year.  Month tacks on a whole bunch of spaces which makes the value look weird.  To fix this you have to trim the Month string prior to appending a follow up string value.

```
select trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(7, 'MM'), 'MONTH')) || ' 2020' month_yr from dual;
```